# Itinerary Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

Use case:

A user is able to create an :itinerary which has many :days (i.e. Hong Kong Itinerary: Day 1, Day 2, Day 3 etc) and each :day has a :description

I am not sure how I should deal with the Itinerary, Day , Description.

Should I create a separate models for Itinerary and Day and Description?

```
**itinerary.rb** 
has_many :days

**day.rb** 
has_one :description
```

But wouldn't this be so confusing? Is there a simpler way you would do it?

Or should I create the model "Day" and have :description as an attribute? If that's the case, how will I order the Day instances (i.e. in the sequence of Day 1, Day 2, Day 3 etc)

Comment: if you don't have many attributes on the `description` table, then only `day` table will do. Just add the `description` table attributes to `day` table.

Comment: How do I sort the "Days" in the order of Day 1, Day 2, Day 3 etc.

Comment: You can sort them based on `created_at` date. Because first created day is Day 1, 2nd created day is Day 2  and so on

Comment: The issue could be, the user might create Day 2 first, then Day 1, in a random order.

Comment: First tell me how can you distinguish which is Day1 and which is Day2

Comment: :title :description

Comment: add an extra field on `day` model. Like integer type **day_no**. User will add specify the day number then. You can also sort them based on that new attribute

Comment: Brilliant. How can I vote this as the answer?

Comment: If days are always called like Day 1 and Day 2, why can't you sort them alphabetically by title? :)

Comment: Hmm true. Common sense has left me for a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if you don't have many **attributes** on the `description` table, then only `day` table will do. Just add the `description` table **attributes** to `day` table.
- add an extra field on `day` model. Like integer type **day_no**. User will add specify the day number there. You can then sort days based on that new attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Create two models `Itinerary` and `Day` ; then add associations as follows :

```
class Itinerary < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :days
end

class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :itinerary
end
```

Day model should have attributes - `:itinerary_id` , `:description`

Now you can get all days of a particular itinerary sequentially by calling - `@itinerary.days`

Kindly note that the sequence depends on the order in which you created the days. In case you're creating days randomly, then add an extra column `:day_index` where you can store integers for representing the days. 
In this case, the sequential call should be - `@itinerary.days.order(:day_index)`

Hope this clears your doubt! :)